# Find duplicate rows based on functions and not the original contents

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table `logs` with two columns that contains log messages:

```
time TIMESTAMP
message STRING
```

I want to select all the messages that match the pattern `job .+ got machine (\d+)` where there are duplicate machines. e.g. given the rows:

```
10000, "job foo got machine 10"
10010, "job bar got machine 10"
10010, "job baz got machine 20"
```

The query will select the first two rows.

I can select the machine that are duplicated with the query:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(message, r'job .+ got machine (\d+)') machine_id
FROM
  [logs]
WHERE
  REGEXP_MATCH(message, r'job .+ got machine \d+')
GROUP BY
  machine_id
HAVING
  COUNT(message) > 1
```

but I can't work out how to go from here to getting the rows containing these machines. I have tried the following:

```
SELECT
  [time],
  message,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(message, r'job .+ got machine (\d+)') machine_id
FROM
  [logs]
WHERE
  REGEXP_MATCH(message, r'job .+ got machine \d+')
HAVING
  machine_id IN (
  SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(message, r'job .+ got machine (\d+)') machine_id
  FROM
    [logs]
  WHERE
    REGEXP_MATCH(message, r'job .+ got machine \d+')
  GROUP BY
    machine_id
  HAVING
    COUNT(message) > 1)
```

But this gives the error "Error: Field 'machine_id' not found".

Is it possible to do what I want in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT [time], message 
FROM (
  SELECT [time], message, machine_id, 
    COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY machine_id) AS dups
  FROM (
    SELECT [time], message,
      REGEXP_EXTRACT(message, r'job .+ got machine (\d+)') machine_id
    FROM 
      [logs]
  )
)
WHERE dups > 1
```

No joins, less clunky

or to simplify even more:

```
SELECT [time], message FROM (
  SELECT [time], message, 
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(message, r'job .+ got machine (\d+)') machine_id,
    COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY machine_id) AS dups
  FROM 
      [logs]
)
WHERE dups > 1
```

Comment: Those look mich nicer! Unfortunately on my dataset they blow up with "Resources exceeded during query execution". That's on 28101819 rows (10.8GB of data) - that wasn't part of the question though, so I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this with the following query:

```
SELECT
  [time],
  message
FROM (
  SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(message, r'job .+ got machine (\d+)') machine_id
  FROM
    [logs]
  WHERE
    REGEXP_MATCH(message, r'job .+ got machine \d+')
  GROUP BY
    machine_id
  HAVING
    COUNT(message) > 1) AS A
JOIN (
  SELECT
    [time],
    message,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(message, r'job .+ got machine (\d+)') machine_id
  FROM    
    [logs]
  WHERE
    REGEXP_MATCH(message, r'job .+ got machine \d+')) AS B
ON
    A.machine_id = B.machine_id
```

which feels slightly clunky but seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

don't use HAVING in that context, just use WHERE

```
SELECT
  [time],
  message,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(message, r'job .+ got machine (\d+)') machine_id
FROM
  [logs]
WHERE
  REGEXP_MATCH(message, r'job .+ got machine \d+')
  AND REGEXP_EXTRACT(message, r'job .+ got machine (\d+)') IN (
  SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(message, r'job .+ got machine (\d+)') machine_id
  FROM
    [logs]
  WHERE
    REGEXP_MATCH(message, r'job .+ got machine \d+')
  GROUP BY
    machine_id
  HAVING
    COUNT(message) > 1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that fails with the message "Expression on the left side of IN has to be a field. Found EXTRACT_REGEXP.". But I have managed to solve this, and I will document it below.